# Multi-Line Graph: Stuck with the json-dict format for the lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, data-visualization

Hello I am totally new to using Python for data visualisation, I have this json response:

```
{
"max365": 83.87,
"current365": 83.87,
"min365": 75.29,

"max180": 76.94,
"current180": 76.94,
"min180": 56.43,

"max90": 98.66,
"current90": 98.66,
"min90": 63.29,

"max30": 138.14,
"current30": 136,
"min30": 66.77,

"max14": 156.93,
"current14": 122.88,
"min14": 72.56,

"max7": 168.9,
"current7": 122.68,
"min7": 74.08,

"max0": 267.5,
"current0": 81.28,
"min0": 36.07 }
```

`max`, `current` and `min` are the lines I would like to plot on a multi-line graph, but I am struggling with the data in this date/time-grouping format with the response.

I've added a screenshot of a graph here that I am essentially trying to reverse engineer:

[image: Multi-line graph - "Volatility Cone"]

I've seen some useful posts for generic line graphs, but my issue here is mostly linking all the max/current/mins onto their own lines whilst I have 0/7/14/30/90/180/365 grouping/intersecting each of them in the response.

Hope I've explained it well enough. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python standard library has a [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json), you need to import just the `loads` method, and massage a little bit the data.

[image]

… and here it is the code — I'd like to underline that we need to split the labels to get out the real label and the sequence info(¿are the numbers time? I made an educated guess), so for each label we construct a list of lists, each element a time and a value, then we sort the lists inside each labelled list and finally we plot the three lines.

```
 from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots
 from json import loads
 
 def split_num(s):
     num = []
     for c in reversed(s):
         if c.isdigit():
             num += c
         else:
             break
     if num:
         return s[:-len(num)], ''.join(reversed(num))
     else:
         return s, ''
 
 json = '''{
     "max365": 83.87,"current365": 83.87,"min365": 75.29,
     "max180": 76.94,"current180": 76.94,"min180": 56.43,
     "max90": 98.66,"current90": 98.66,"min90": 63.29,
     "max30": 138.14,"current30": 136,"min30": 66.77,
     "max14": 156.93,"current14": 122.88,"min14": 72.56,
     "max7": 168.9,"current7": 122.68,"min7": 74.08,
     "max0": 267.5,"current0": 81.28,"min0": 36.07 }'''
 jdict = loads(json)
 
 data = {}
 for k in jdict:
     name, num = split_num(k)
     data[name] = data.setdefault(name, []) + [[int(num), float(jdict[k])]]
 for k in data: data[k] = sorted(data[k])
 
 fig, ax = subplots()
 for k in data:
     ax.plot(*zip(*data[k]), label=k)
 ax.legend()
 fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks so much - I can see from your graph that you've got it correct. However simply running your code the graph itself isn't showing for me but I'll play around and figure that out.

Comment: Solution works in Jupyter.

Comment: @GundamWing ፨ I have executed the code in the interactive interpreter and it works "as is", but to have it work as a script you have to make two small changes: ① first line, change to `from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots, show`, ② last line, change to `show()` (without  `fig.`  prepended). HTH